# How to slide a map on a textView from right of screen

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments, transition

I have a detail screen which is fragment, in middle of it I have a linear layout with 2 textViews. I want to slide a map view from right of screen over the linear layout using a button, see picture below:

[image: Map should slide over address with the button]

Anyone can help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [**Android ViewPager**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) to slide the map fragment back and forth over your textView.

Here is a [**tutorial**](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) if you want to start.

Comment: thanks for reply, I am already using ViewPager for other parts of that page, but View pager doesn't have handle or button or can't manage to show part of map like image, I need something like slider view which is deprecated!